# React Routing Menu - data handling best practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a menu for my React application like so:

[image]

the list itself is easy enough. but now I have the main component that contains 2 sub-components:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MenuBar/>
      <DisplayPane/>
    )
  }
}
```

the `MenuBar` Component holds all the menu building logic, and there are a bunch of `Link` components in it.
The `DisplayPane` component has several `Route` components:

```
class DisplayPane extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Route path="/a" component={A} />
      <Route path="/b" component={B} />
      <Route path="/c" component={C} />
    )
  }
}
```

but now I have a problem that whenever I want to add/remove/modify a component/route, I need to update on 2 places, which to me doesn't make sense.

**Is that the react way to handle this situation or is it some pattern to do this kind of menus in React so the maintenance is more reasonable?**

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine to me. But if you want a more generic approach to it you could create a separate file to store the actual component bindings and its route and iterate through to dynamically generates the routes and its link. You could do something like this:

### Route.js

```
export default [
    {
        path : "/a",
        component : A,
        target : "",
        isExact : true // You can add more objects to configure your route/link
    },
    {
        path : "/b",
        component : B,
        target : "",
        isExact : true
    },
    {
        path : "/c",
        component : C,
        target : "",
        isExact : true
    },
]
```

You can import your components in `Route.js` and map them against `component` property.
You can import `Route.js` inside your `DisplayPane` and `MenuBar` and iterate through it to generate dynamic routes.

### DisplayPane.js

```
class DisplayPane extends Component {
    render() {
      return routesObj.map((route,index)=> {
          return <Route key={index} exact={route.isExact} path={route.path} component={route.component}/>
        })
    }
  }
```

Similarly you can also import the same object inside `MenuBar` and use `map` there to render the `Link`. this way you would just need to make another object inside the array and map will take care of it for you.

Comment: here is the issue with this approach that I can't quite figure out if is very harmful or just a bit: this Route.js is util at best, and in this approach, the util is importing components, breaking the layers structure